# thread unsafe async in List<>.ForEach()

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

Why is it threadunsafe to do an `await` inside a `.ForEach()` ?

In a .Net Core 3.1 project I'm Selecting from some WebApi, the list of users matching a criteria, then I delete them, and finally I ask for the list of users again. Naturally, this time I expect the list to be empty.

The **erroneous** code

```
    var existing = (await client.GetByMatchAsync(new SearchParameters() {..})).ToList();

    existing.ForEach(async x => await client.DeleteByIdAsync(x.Id));

    var ensure = (await client.GetByMatchAsync(new SearchParameters() {..})).ToList();
    ensure.Count.Should().Be(0);  <-- ERROR WAS 1!
```

I've found that when I insert a `Thread.Sleep(50)` before `var ensure` the code works. This clearly indicates to me that there are threading issues going on I don't understand.

the **working** code (using a delay)

```
            var existing = (await client.GetByMatchAsync(new SearchParameters() {..})).ToList();

            existing.ForEach(async x => await client.DeleteByIdAsync(x.Id));
            Thread.Sleep(50);

            var ensure = (await client.GetByMatchAsync(new SearchParameters() {..})).ToList();
            ensure.Count.Should().Be(0);
```

Alternative **Working** code (using foreach)

```
            var existing = (await client.GetByMatchAsync(new SearchParameters() {..})).ToList();

            foreach (var x in existing)
            {
                await client.DeleteByIdAsync(x.Id);
            }

            var ensure = (await client.GetByMatchAsync(new SearchParameters() {..})).ToList();
            ensure.Count.Should().Be(0);
```

decompiling the `.ForEach()` I can't see where the threading problem occur

```
    public void ForEach(Action<T> action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.action);
        }

        int version = _version;

        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            if (version != _version)
            {
                break;
            }
            action!(_items[i]);
        }

        if (version != _version)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion();
    }
```

Comment: .ForEach() just takes an action, not a Func<Task> and you therefore never await it.

Comment: `existing.ForEach` starts a bunch of tasks, not waiting for them to complete, so they all are in flight at the same time. `foreach {await}` awaits the previous task before starting the next one.

Comment: In the ForEach decompile, action!(_items[i]); is a strange statement what is with the exclamation mark?

Comment: @CRice Ask ReSharper what the `!` mean ;)

Comment: @CRice - [null-forgiving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) I think

Comment: This exactly question is described as #5 [here](https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List's ForEach just takes an `Action<T>` so the action you provide is not awaited per iteration, and execution can continue before the call is completed.

Otherwise it would likely have an overload with the signature

```
Task ForEach(Func<T, Task> func)
```

What I thought was strange is that the following line compiles, but you can't assign a `Func<T, Task>` to an `Action<T>`.

```
Action<string> a = async (value) => await Task.CompletedTask;
```

The fact you could invoke the ForEach this way was misleading.

```
existing.ForEach(async x => await client.DeleteByIdAsync(x.Id));
```

Comment: Since I'm not sure, I will just ask: Are you still confused that `async (value) => await Task.CompletedTask` can be assigned to both `Fun<string, Task>` and `Action<string>`?

Comment: @Ackdari I see that it can like this but you cant assign an instance of one to the other if made at separate times - there's no implicit conversion.